# Code Snippet Section

Tags: support, research

Is it possible to let users add some valueable code to a section specified by a tag?

So if a user with the aid of other users develop some interesting code to do something, when people look for code snippets they should search this first.

Comment: Google has this *huge* repo of code snippets that its employees use (internally). This may be a good idea if its well executed.

Comment: Did not knw that, cool!

Comment: @Reno, any link to those snippets?

Comment: Don't we already have that? You want to do X, the question "how do I do X?" usually has an answer that includes a code snippet showing how to do X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting idea.. I think the snippets should be editable by high-rep users, like questions are.

It could also implement [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/04/a-modest-proposal-for-the-copy-and-paste-school-of-code-reuse.html).

Answer (score -1):

Interesting. Who defines it as interesting? How do you reckon is the best way to narrow down to what you want? Maybe we could have a contextual search engine that knew how to narrow down the results based on language and context? If only Google solved that very problem ...

Since I apparently need to back this up with SEI quotes and links, here's some to entertain you:

From Area51: (any site statistics screen for a beta)

> 1,500 visits per day is good, 500 visits per day is worrying. A great site benefits people outside the community. Eventually, 90% of a site's traffic should come from search engines.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/blekko-and-stack-overflow/

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/the-perfect-web-spider-storm/

Seriously, SEI is all about SEO and having Google et al link back into the SE2.0 architecture to do the cataloging and searching for them. I don't understand what this proposal brings to the table that Google et al do not.

Comment: Maybe google will in 5 years, maybe instead of interesting I should write `helpul`

Comment: @darkcminor - I think you'll find that was sarcasam, as that's exactly what google do.

Comment: I don't understand. I already use Google to find interesting snippets of code that solve my problems _as is_ ... what are you asking for that Google doesn't help with? If I want to see spiffy code I can either goto http://codegolf.stackexchange.com or http://codereview.stackexchange.com ...

Comment: Thanks @Farseeker, I see it wasn't lost on everybody

Comment: I think I would search here first, as I `trust` more in stackoverflow